# Uploading multiple image fields to each row in server mysql

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

In my post page i have multiple upload fields.

```
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"

    class="form-horizontal">

    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
    <label for="image">Big pic</label>
    <input id="image" type="file" name="image" class="btn btn-danger">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group col-md-5">
     <label for="img_v1">V1</label>
     <input id="img_v1" type="file" name="img_v1" class="btn btn-danger">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group col-md-5">
    <label for="img_v2">V2</label>
    <input id="img_v2" type="file" name="img_v2" class="btn btn-danger">
    </div>
```

And i want to upload each field to each row in my server.

my upload script is in the same file.

```
$error = ''; 
if(isset($_POST['submit_post'])){
$title = strip_tags($_POST['title']);
$date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
if($_FILES['image']['name'] !=''){
$image_name = $_FILES['image']['name']; 
$image_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$image_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
$image_ext = pathinfo($image_name,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$image_path = '../clientes/img/'.$image_name;
$image_db_path = 'img/'.$image_name;
if($image_size < 10000000){
if($image_ext == 'jpg' || $image_ext == 'png' || $image_ext == 'jpeg' ||       $image_ext == 'gif'){
if(move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,$image_path)){
$ins_sql = "INSERT INTO gallery (title, description, image, category,   status) VALUES ('$title', '$_POST[description]',
 '$image_db_path', '$_POST[category]', '$_POST[status]')";
  if(mysqli_query($conn,$ins_sql)){
  header('post_list.php');
 }else{
  $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Erro de script</div>';
  }
  }else{
  '<div class="alert alert-danger">Image cant upload</div>';
  } 
  }else{
  $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Wrong image extention</div>';
  }
  }else{
  $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Image is to much big</div>';
  }
  }else{
  $ins_sql = "INSERT INTO gallery (title, description, category, status,     date, author) VALUES ('$title', '$_POST[description]', 
  '$_POST[category]', '$_POST[status]', '$date', '$_SESSION[userName]    $_SESSION[userLName]')";
  if(mysqli_query($conn,$ins_sql)){
  header('post_list.php');
  }else{
  $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Script error</div>';
  }
  }
  }
```

i tried to upload the 3 fields to the server like this...

INSERT INTO gallery (title, description, **image,img_v1, img_v2** category, status) VALUES    ('$title', '$_POST[description]',
**'$image_db_path','$image_db_path','$image_db_path'**, '$_POST[category]', '$_POST[status]')";

But i know it was wrong.
What i have to do so i can upload the extra img fields?

Comment: when you don't check for errors, you don't know what to look for, which is a syntax error in your query. We also don't know if you started the session or not.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: @tadman thx for that tip, i'm still learning php,i will study the stuffs u said. big thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed one comma between img_v2 and category.

```
INSERT INTO gallery (title, description, image,img_v1, img_v2, category, status) VALUES ('$title', '$_POST[description]', '$image_db_path','$image_db_path','$image_db_path', '$_POST[category]', '$_POST[status]')";
```

Comment: ohh god i kept like 15 in my code trying to find whats wrong. and it was only a comma geez

Comment: thx bro, i think that i was going to keep an hour trying to find out lol

Comment: Your code is wrong, but this gets it barely working. You've still got a lot of work to do.

Comment: @JamesAllan No problem mate, if it solved it, can you mark my answer as the right one? This add me some rep, thanks :).

Comment: Sorry i forgot that =D